# Numpy filtering using array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing, slice

I know this has been asked before but there doesn't seem to be anything for my specific use-case.

I have a numpy array `obs` which represents a color image and has shape `(252, 288, 3)`.

I want to convert every pixel that is not pure black to pure white.

What I have tried is `obs[obs != [0, 0, 0]] = [255, 255, 255]` but it gives the following exception:

`ValueError: NumPy boolean array indexing assignment cannot assign 3 input values to the 807 output values where the mask is true`

The result is the same with`obs[obs[:, :] != [0, 0, 0]] = [255, 255, 255]`. Also, `(obs[:, :] != [0, 0, 0]).shape` is `(252, 288, 3)` and I do not understand why it isnt simply `(252, 288)` (a matrix of bools).

I thought about using `obs[obs != 0] = 255` but that would not have the effect I want since a pixel that is pure green (`[0, 255, 0]`) would be processed component wise and would still be `[0, 255, 0]` after the filtering, instead of being actually white (`[255, 255, 255]`).

Why isn't what I have tried up until now working and how should I go about this?

Comment: is not this what you want? obs[obs != 0] = 255

Comment: @Stepan I have literally explained that in the question. I have corrected a few typos, it should be more clear now.

Comment: Surely a single-channel (greyscale) or even a Boolean (True/False) result is enough to represent your desired black/white output without needing 3x the RAM as you would for an RGB result containing only black and white?

Answer (score 5):

Boolean indexing like `obs[obs != [0, 0, 0]]` return a 1D array with all the elements from `obs` that satisfy the given condition.
Look at the follwoing example:

```
obs = np.array([
 [[88, 0,99],
  [ 0, 0, 0]],
 [[ 0, 0, 0],
  [88,77,66]]
])
```

`obs != [0, 0, 0]` returns a boolean array:

```
array([[[ True, False,  True],
        [False, False, False]],
       [[False, False, False],
        [ True,  True,  True]]])
```

and `obs[obs != [0, 0, 0]]` then returns a 1D array with all the elements where the mask is `True`: `array([88, 99, 88, 77, 66])`.

So what you need is [`where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to test if there's [`any`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) color component not equal 0:

```
np.where(obs.any(axis=-1, keepdims=True), 255, obs)
```

Result:

```
array([[[255, 255, 255],
        [  0,   0,   0]],
       [[  0,   0,   0],
        [255, 255, 255]]])
```

Note that you need `keepdims=True` to enable broadcasting to the original shape of `obs`. Otherwise you'd have to add the lost dimension by `np.where(obs.any(-1)[...,np.newaxis], 255, obs)` or `np.where(np.atleast_3d(obs.any(-1)), 255, obs)` which is less elegant.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of possibilities depending what you actually want to do. Let's do the set-up code (which is common to all possibilities) first so you can see what I mean.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np

# Make a repeatable random image
np.random.seed(764)
obs = np.random.randint(0,32,(252,288,3), dtype=np.uint8)
```

This image happens to have pure black pixels at the following locations for test purposes:

```
obs[ 21, 267]
obs[ 28, 252]
obs[ 69, 127]
obs[ 98,   0]
obs[124, 210]
obs[133,  98]
obs[160,  81]
obs[167,  48]
obs[217, 237]
```

---

Now, suppose you want a new, pure True/False boolean mask of black pixels, you can use:

```
mask = obs.any(axis=-1)
```

That solution has the following characteristics:

```
time: 876 µs
mask.shape: (252,288)
mask.nbytes: 72576
mask.dtype: 'bool'
```

You can subsequently use and re-use that mask like this:

```
# Make masked pixels red
obs[mask,:] = [255,0,0]

# Make unmasked pixels cyan
obs[~mask,:] = [0,255,255]
```

[image]

---

Now let's suppose you want a new, greyscale image, with black and white pixels, you can use:

```
grey = obs.any(axis=-1) * np.uint8(255)
```

That solution has the following characteristics:

```
time: 887 µs
grey.shape: (252,288)
grey.nbytes: 72576
grey.dtype: np.uint8
```

---

Now suppose you want in-place alteration of your already existing "obs" to pure black and white (but still RGB):

```
obs[obs.any(axis=-1),:] = [255,255,255]
```

That solution has the following characteristics:

```
time: 1.98 ms
obs.shape: (252,288,3)
obs.nbytes: 217728
obs.dtype: np.uint8
```